# Meaning of "Then again"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, expressions

> "***Then again***, it didn't matter, did it?"

What's the meaning of ***"then again"*** here?

Is it the same as ***"thinking better"***?

Comment: **[then/there again](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/again#then-there-again)** "*mainly spoken*
used for introducing a statement that makes what you have just said seem less true, or that is the opposite of what you have just said. *I suppose Elaine might help; then again she might not. The hotel was awful. But then again, you can't expect much for $30 a night.*"

Answer (score 4):

"Then again" is used to introduce an afterthought or second thought to a previous statement. Depending on the tone of the speaker, it can mean "thinking better of it..." or "on the other hand." The latter usage elicits a spoken emphasis on the verb (especially a modal).

> I didn't want Larry to see what happened... then again I figured as a
>   doctor, maybe he could help me. (= thinking better of it)

|

> I don't want Larry to see what happened. Then again he *is* a
>   doctor. (=on the other hand)

Answer (score 1):

"Then again" would only be synonymous with "thinking better [of...]" when the prior thought was negative. "On the other hand" (or "then again") could be used in either circumstance.

[Something negative]; thinking better of it, [something positive].

[Something positive or negative]; on the other hand, [something opposite].

In both cases, the second statement opposes the first, but the inclusion of "better" implies a positive meaning to the second statement.

Answer (score 1):

Then again mean "however" or "on the other hand"