# The usage of "until" in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, adverbs

Someone wrote:

> **Then again** I came back to the taxi with completely wet clothes **till the driver repaired it after 30 mintues**.

The context is:

> the taxi became punctured ... 
>   I left the taxi and stood alongside the freeway in the rain to catch another taxi, but after 10 minutes had passed, no taxi had stopped for me in that rainy weather.

I know **Then again** is false  according to [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29881/meaning-of-then-again). It could be simply "again", right? or any other alternative?

But I also think it lacks " and **waited** till the driver ...", because I think some activity should be performed before "until" right?

My suggestion is:

> I came back again to the taxi with completely wet clothes, and waited until the driver repaired the taxi after 30 mintues.

Also, what is the proper verb tense after "until" in the past or present sentences?

Comment: the repaired it doesn't fit with the antecedent (what comes before it). And: till the driver repaired it after 30 minutes is not idiomatic. /until, 30 minutes later, the driver had repaired it.

Comment: We cannot "come back ... *until*" or "return ... *until*"  unless the reference is to a repeated action. *We came back|returned to the restaurant many times until it changed owners.*  When *came back* is a perfective (an action which has completion) it cannot be modified by *until*.  So your suggestion to add *waited* (an action that does not have completion) is a good one.  We can say "I slept until 9AM" but not "I awoke until 9AM".

Comment: @tromano well. Then it's repeated, continues or takes time to be done. I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my conception, "*then again*" can also be used in the beginning. I guess "*with*" doesn't suit with clothes, "*with completely wet clothes*" doesn't sound very good, how about replacing it by the verb "*wearing*" in order to make this sentece sound more fluent? And as you have told me, now I can understand your question fully, so you meant you wanted to wait for the driver to finish up the car repair? So, you could rewrite this sentence using until too, here are some suggestions:

> Then again, I came back to the taxi wearing completely wet clothes and waited until the driver finishes up the car repairs.
>
> Then again, I came back to the taxi with my clothes full of water and waited for the driver to fix the car.
>
> Then again, I came back to the taxi wearing clothes full of water and waited for the driver to finish up the car repairs

Comment: Sorry! I think you got the story wrongly. I should have added more context. I did it now.

Comment: Oh, you meant the taxi had been broken and the driver fixed it?

Comment: Right.............

Comment: Now I got it, so this would be my suggestion: **I came back to the taxi with my  clothes full of water and waited for the driver to repair the car.** Or: **I came back to the taxi wearing clothes full of water and waited until the driver fixes the car.**

Comment: Then you agree that "wait" is required. You also used present tense after until. Why? You may add the reason to your question.

Comment: Yeah, if you were waiting for something, then you need to increase this, unless you weren't waiting for this, then you can replace this verb for any other, but it sounded to me that you intended to say that you were waiting for him to finish up the car repairs

Comment: Until + present tense: _I waited until he was done_ _He waited until I finish my task_ _I'm waiting until you finish it_ _She waits until he finishes it_

Comment: You also used present tense after until. Why? You may add the reason to your question or here.

Comment: If you use the word "until" it dooesn't change the present tense's rules, which is adding the 's' after 3third persons noun, but, what's your real question? You want to know whether you can use the present tense after "until"? If it is what you want to know, yeah, you can use both present tense, past tense, present perfect tense, future tense..

I will be waiting here until you finish your task
I was waiting there until he finished his task
They are waiting in my house until you finish it

Comment: You said "**waited** until the driver **finishes** up the car repairs." Is it "finished" or "has finished" or "had finished"?

Comment: It's up to you, you can either use finishes, had finished, or finished. As your sentence is written in the past, and you are telling a past history, you can write it in the past perfect tense: 

**Then again, I came back to the taxi wearing clothes full of water and waited until the driver had finished up the car repairs.**

Present:

**Then again, I came back to the taxi wearing clothes full of water and waited until the driver finishes the car repairs.**

Past: **Then again, I came back to the taxi wearing clothes full of water and waited until the driver finished the car repairs.**

Comment: I'd opt to use the past perfect tense in that sentence, considering that your statement is written in the past tense, i.e, you are telling a past history, so all the others completements should also be written in the past tense and past perfect tense.