# The verb tense after "Until"

Tags: tense, verbs, adverbs

I asked a [related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113734/the-usage-of-until-in-this-sentence), which its answer's comments say I can use different tense after "Until", I thought of posting the question in a separate question to get a complete answer.

Which of the following are possible or more natural

> - I waited until he left the room, then I entered there
> - I waited until he leaves the room, then I entered there
> - I waited until he had left the room, then I entered there

I know it could also be the following, but I didn't find a better example with "until". If you know use that.

- I waited for him to leave the room

What about present:

> - I am waiting until he comes back
> - I am waiting until he will come back
> - I wait until he comes back

Or

> - I can't help you until I finish/have finished my work

Comment: The tense of the verb *after* until is governed but the verb *before* until.

Comment: @Peter but still there are several options.

Comment: None of the sentences has an ending punctuation. They can reasonably be considered incorrect (grammatically). And in the case of your question, I prefer #1 from the first three and #1 and #3 in the second three.

Comment: Note that *I waited for him to leave the room* and *I waited until he left to enter the room* are not the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahmad, it follows the same rules as the past question. 
All tenses mentioned can be used in that sentence. However, as it's a past tense and you are telling a past history, using "had" would make it sound more fluent.

> I waited until he had left the room, then I entered there.

Now talking about your second question.

> I am waiting until he comes back  - **Right**
>
> I am waiting until he will come back - **Wrong**
>
> I wait until he comes back - **Right**

Remember, "*until*" cannot be used followed by the *future tense*, all the others alternatives are suitable for until, past tense, *past continuous*, *present tense*, *present continuous*, *present perfect*..

And *I waited for him to leave the room* also works and sounds good too, and functions with others tenses too:

I was waiting for him to leave the room

I will be waiting for him to leave the room;

I waited for him to leave the room

I have been waiting for him to leave the room.